# How to disable C, Ruby, Puppet and others in SublimeLinter plugin?

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, sublimelinter

Simply, I want to disable linting for languages I do not use. This is my User Config file content:

```
{ 
"sublimelinter": true, 
"sublimelinter_executable_map": { "php":"/usr/bin/php" },
"sublimelinter_mark_style": "outline",
"sublimelinter_gutter_marks_theme": "hard",
"sublimelinter_popup_errors_on_save": true,
"sublimelinter_notes": true,

"sublimelinter_disable":
[
    {
        "ruby": "ruby",
        "c": "c"
    }
]
}
```

doesn't help. When I restart ST2 and open terminal, there it is:

```
SublimeLinter: C loaded
SublimeLinter: ruby-lint loaded
SublimeLinter: haskell loaded
SublimeLinter: Ruby loaded
SublimeLinter: HTML loaded
SublimeLinter: Puppet loaded
SublimeLinter: Java loaded
```

Answer (score 2):

Any language listed in the sublimelinter_disable list is not enabled for linting.  Having the language listed as "loaded" does not mean it is enabled.  See further down in your console output for the list of languages actually enabled.  Here is an example line in my configuration:

```
SublimeLinter: css enabled (using node.js)
```

Edited:
   To remove the list of languages from the config entirely you need to remove the .py and .pyc files related to that language in the SublimeLinter/sublimelinter/modules directory.  Worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

The comment in `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings` says:

```
// An array of linter names to disable. Names should be lowercase.
"sublimelinter_disable":
[
]
```

Have you tried to simply add

```
"sublimelinter_disable":
["ruby", "c"]
```

?